# Error con los datos al dibujar una gráfica

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, chart.js

soy nuevo en el tema de javascript y tengo una duda con respecto al tema de realizar graficas dinamicamente.

Tengo una grafica la cual al cambiar de año me muestra son los datos del año anterior y no del que seleccione.

LA SOLUCIÓN ES RECREAR EL DIV JUNTO CON EL CANVAS pero no he podido, quien ma colabora por favor :(.

*SOLUCIÓN -> lo que deberias hacer dentro del a funcion, es primero recrear el div junto con el canvas para que la informacion sea nueva y no implantada.﻿

```
    <div class="resultados"><canvas id="grafico"></canvas></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(mostrarResultados(2000));  
            function mostrarResultados(año){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'controlador/procesar.php',
                    data:'año='+año,
                    success:function(data){

                        var valores = eval(data);

                        var e   = valores[0];
                        var f   = valores[1];
                        var m   = valores[2];
                        var a   = valores[3];
                        var ma  = valores[4];
                        var j   = valores[5];
                        var jl  = valores[6];
                        var ag  = valores[7];
                        var s   = valores[8];
                        var o   = valores[9];
                        var n   = valores[10];
                        var d   = valores[11];

                        var Datos = {
                                labels : ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
                                datasets : [
                                    {
                                        fillColor : 'rgba(91,228,146,0.6)', //COLOR DE LAS BARRAS
                                        strokeColor : 'rgba(57,194,112,0.7)', //COLOR DEL BORDE DE LAS BARRAS
                                        highlightFill : 'rgba(73,206,180,0.6)', //COLOR "HOVER" DE LAS BARRAS
                                        highlightStroke : 'rgba(66,196,157,0.7)', //COLOR "HOVER" DEL BORDE DE LAS BARRAS
                                        data : [e, f, m, a, ma, j, jl, ag, s, o, n, d]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }

                        var contexto = document.getElementById('grafico').getContext('2d');
                        window.Barra = new Chart(contexto).Bar(Datos, { responsive : true });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Si ya solucionaste esta pregunta, puedes agregar tu mismo la respuesta, tomo como base [answer], saludos.

Comment: No lo he solucionado, esa es la solución sino que no he podido implementarla, por ese motivo genera la pregunta, tengo el concepto pero no he podido plasmarlo.saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo para ti un ejemplo de código que puedes modificar a conveniencia. Me parece apropiado para realizar de forma bien estructurada lo que estas pidiendo, está todo bastante bien comentado. Solamente le faltaría el efecto `hover` pero eso te lo dejo a ti. Puedes ver cómo se ejecuta dando click en el botón `ejecutar` que aparece al final del comentario.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', main, false);

function main() {

  /// constantes
  var ML = 50;   // Margen izquierdo
  var MR = 50;  // Margen derecho
  var MB = 30; // Margen inferior
  var MT = 60;    // Margen superior
  var ST = 30;    // Separacion entre las barras
  
  var DATA = {
    "2014" : [ 12, 7, 29, 6, 11, 4, 5, 8 ],
    "2015" : [ 5, 5, 7, 6, 12, 44, 21, 3, 9],
    "2016" : [ 2, 5, 1, 3, 4, 6],
    "2017" : [ 23, 45, 16, 48, 34, 11 ],
  };
  
  var SETTINGS = {
    fillColor       : 'rgba(91, 228, 146, 0.6)',
    strokeColor     : 'rgba(57, 194, 112, 0.7)',
    highlightFill   : 'rgba(73, 206, 180, 0.6)',
    highlightStroke : 'rgba(66, 196, 157, 0.7)'
  };
 
  /// Funcion para dibujar
  
  var cnv = document.querySelector('#canvas');
  var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
  
  ctx.fillStyle = SETTINGS.fillColor;
  ctx.strokeStyle = SETTINGS.strokeColor;
  
  var drawData = function drawData( year) {
    
    if (year in DATA) {
    
      /// Maximo de la lista
      var MX = DATA[year][0];
      var len = DATA[year].length;
      
      for (let i = 1; i < len; i += 1) {
        if (DATA[year][i] > MX) {
          MX = DATA[year][i];
        }
      }
      
      /// Maxima longitud de una barra
      var maxHeight = cnv.height - MT - MB;
      
      /// Ancho de cada barra
      var barWidth = ( cnv.width - ML - MR - ST * ( DATA[year].length - 1) ) / DATA[year].length;
    
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
    
      for ( let i = 0; i < len; i += 1 ) {
        
        // Ancho previamente calculado
        let w = barWidth;
        
        // Altura calculada mediante proporciones
        let h = DATA[year][i] * maxHeight / MX;
        
        let x = ML + i * ( ST + barWidth );
        let y = cnv.height - MB - h;
        
        ctx.fillRect( x, y, w, h );
        ctx.strokeRect( x, y, w, h );
        
      }
    
    } else {
      throw new ReferenceError('Invalid year');
    }
  
  };
  
  /// agregar el evento click a cada elemento de la lista
  
  document.querySelectorAll('.yearPicker').forEach(function(li) {
    li.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      drawData( e.target.getAttribute('val') );
    });
  });
  
}
```

```css
li {
        list-style: none;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        padding: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 5px;
        background-color: #555;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 2px;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      
      canvas {
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title> Drawing with graphic bars with canvas </title>
    <meta charset="utf8">
  </head>
  
  <body>
    
    <ul>
      <li class="yearPicker" val="2014" > 2014 </li>
      <li class="yearPicker" val="2015" > 2015 </li>
      <li class="yearPicker" val="2016" > 2016 </li>
      <li class="yearPicker" val="2017" > 2017 </li>
    </ul>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400">
      Your browser does not support canvas element. Please, update it!!
    </canvas>
  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, me sirvió de mucho, saludos...

Comment: Ok. Si necesitas algo más puedes escribirme a isaacvega1996@gmail.com

Comment: @Jassan: Tengo hecho un ejemplo parecido pero con el efecto del mouse incluido y un par de mejoras. Si te interesa dime a donde puedo enviartelo.

Comment: si me interesaría para poder aprender estudiarlo y así ir aprendiendo un poco más sobre javascript y el manejo de gráficas, puede ser al de felipear_20@hotmail.com y muchas gracias @Isaac Vega.
Aprovechando te pregunto, porque al momento de ejecutar una consulta que me devuelve 21000 registros se me demora alrededor de 4minutos y en sql 20seg, sera que tengo la consulta mal estructurada para mysql o es porque estoy realizando las pruebas en un equipo local?, Gracias...